# Control native browser scaling through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, fullscreen

Can't seem to find any information on this topic, so here goes:

Suppose I have a web app that can enter the <kbd>F11</kbd> fullscreen using the `requestFullscreen()` browser-specific methods. I'm looking for a way to control the native browser scaling for the app to fill the available fullscreen space (that you normally invoke with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>).

Comment: In what way would you like to control it? (And media queries is not what you're looking for, right?)

Comment: I'd expect the regular set and get control. What I wanna do is grab the available screen space and rescale the app wrapper to fit it with a couple conditions (similarly to video fullscreen scaling).

Comment: Looks like I will have to resort to `transform: scale`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want the `requestFullScreen()` functionality. This is a newer member of the HTML5 draft spec, but its already found its way to a few browsers!

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:FullScreenAPI#Proposed_Specification

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I already have fullscreen functionality implemented as I mentioned, I'm looking for a way to control the browser zoom level instead. From what I learned so far on this topic, it looks like I will have to resort to using `transform: scale`.